# How to enable https with pem ssl certificate?

Tags: spring-boot, ssl, https, pem

I have a SpringBoot back end and I want to enable https. I also have a ssl certificate (or I think so) that contains 4 .pem files and a read me that describes the files like this:

`privkey.pem`  : the private key for your certificate.

`fullchain.pem`: the certificate file used in most server software.

`chain.pem`    : used for OCSP stapling in Nginx >=1.3.7.

`cert.pem`     : will break many server configurations, and should not be used
                 without reading further documentation (see link below).

I tried many guides and ways but couldn't make it work. I'm not sure whitch files am I supposed to use and how. Can someone give me a detailed instruction, how to do this?

I first tried to follow this guide: https://www.thomasvitale.com/https-spring-boot-ssl-certificate/ and used the `fullchain.pem`. I got a `java.io.IOException: jsse.alias_no_key_entry` exception. Then I tried to fix it following this guide: https://www.wowza.com/docs/how-to-import-an-existing-ssl-certificate-and-private-key, using the `fullchain.pem` and the `privkey.pem` as the private key, tho I didn't execute the third command due to the fact that I don't have a ca_bundle (I don't know what it is). It still didn't work.

Comment: 1) a certificate does not contain 4 files. A certificate is (typically) a file, with (typically but absolutely not required) a filename ending in `.pem` or `.crt`, and contains (again typically but not necessarily) a certificate encoded in PEM format. 2) which files you are supposed to use and how depends on your configuration. what did you try? what is your code? what are your errors?

Comment: I added to the question what I tried. Thanks for your time on this.

Comment: `ca_bundle` is `chain.pem` or `fullchain.pem` it depends. private key is only `privkey.pem` and nothing else. `cert.pem` is your certificate

Comment: Why dose it say that will break many server configurations, and should not be used without reading further documentation?